# First, second and third derivative of a vector function

Tags: matlab, vector, maple, differentiation

I can define the following vector function

*f*(*x*, *y*, *z*) = [*x*<sup>2</sup> - 1, *x*<sup>3</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>, *z*]

In MatLab or in Maple.

I want to find (and evaluate) the first, second and third derivatives of it. How to find: ∇*f*, ∇<sup>2</sup>*f* and ∇<sup>3</sup>*f*? Here vector function *f* is differentiated with respect to vector (*x*, *y*, *z*). I can do the simple job of finding ∇*f* with Maple as follows:

*f*(*x*, *y*, *z*) = [*x*<sup>2</sup> - 1, *x*<sup>3</sup> + *y*<sup>2</sup>, *z*]

∇*f* = Jacobian(*f*, [*x*, *y*, *z*])

But how to differentiate ∇*f*?

Is there a function in MatLab (or in Maple) which may take the above function as an input and evaluate its derivatives for a given value of (x, y, z)?

Comment: Nabla and Jacobian are different things.

Comment: Your question has been answered wrt Maple by Acer on math.stackexchange.